# How to exclude a file from a command with ZSH?

Tags: bash, zsh, globbing

Given this directory content :

```
one.file
two.file
three.file
```

in bash, when I enter

```
rm *.file !(two)
```

only `one.file` and `three.file` are deleted. How can I do this in ZSH?

Comment: In fact, you need to use `rm !(two).file` in bash.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was interested in the answer too, and a quick
search turned up this [article on globbing in zsh](http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/37/ZSH-Gem-2-Extended-globbing-and-expansion/). The highlights:

- `^` Acts as a negation. For example, `ls ^two.file` will only list the one.file and three.file.
- You can combine `^` and `*`. For example, `ls ^two*` will list anything that doesn't start with "two"
- You can use parentheses to make more complex matches. For example, `ls (^two).file` will list anything that *doesn't* start with "two", and *does* end in "file".

Comment: Enable extended globbing first: `setopt extended_glob`

Comment: @Emre Thanks a lot, that was the one info that took me 2 hours to find

Comment: @LukasJuhrich lol, you're not alone.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the ksh syntax `ls !(two).file`, simply turn on the `KSH_GLOB` option in zsh:

```
$ setopt KSH_GLOB
$ ls -1 !(two).file
one.file
three.file
```

But zsh provides other powerful globbing techniques, activated by the `EXTENDED_GLOB` option. For a complete list, please read the section *FILENAME GENERATION* in `man zshexpn`. Most relevant to the question are these operators:

- `^x` matches anything except the pattern *x*, so in your case `ls -1 ^two.file`
- `x~y` is more powerful as it matches anything that matches the pattern *x* but does not  match *y*, so `ls -1 *~two.file`. The special thing is, that you have can use another globbing pattern for *x*, e.g.

  ```
  $ ls -1 *.file~two*
  one.file
  three.file
  ```

  This is not possible with the `^` operator, which is in this case equivalent to `*~`:

  ```
  $ ls -1 *.file^two*
  one.file
  three.file
  two.file
  ```